# How to identify(DEV,QA,PROD) environment in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I just need the information how to identify whether is it DEV or 
QA or PROD environment.

I have tried by using `Sys_context`. But i did not get the exact information.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can usually distinguish between different DBs by querying the service name of the DB...

```
select global_name from global_name
```

... or from the `userenv` context...

```
sys_context('userenv', 'db_name')
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I guess Dev or Prod is just the way you use your database... 
There is no difference between a prod database or a dev database in the architecture.

The users, the priveleges, and the size may change, but you can also have a test environment which is just an exact copy of prod...

you should ask your dba or im team